# How prove this inequality??

Tags: inequality

> How prove :
>
> ---

$$
{31}^{11}<{17}^{14}
$$

---

> help please!

Comment: With some extimations, I guess. I would not make the whole calculation, if I were you!

Comment: There is a big gap between the expressions, so this doesn't look too hard.

Answer (score 18):

I showed the numbers in diferent way:

${17}^{14}>{16}^{14}$

${16}^{14}={2^4}^{14}=2^{56}$

$17^{14}>2^{56}$

${31}^{11}<{32}^{11}$

$32^{11}={2^5}^{11}=2^{55}$

$2^{55}<2^{56}$

$17^{14}>2^{56}>2^{55}>31^{11}$

I think i show it more clear :)

Comment: Please use formatting

Comment: @magdaj You are the same person as xhr, aren't you? If so, please request an account merge. (http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 16):

$31^{11} < 32^{11} = 2^{55} < 2^{56} = 2^{4 \cdot 14} = 16^{14} < 17^{14}$

Answer (score 7):

$$31^{11} < 32^{11} = (2^5)^{11}=2^{55} < 2^{56}=(2^4)^{14}=16^{14} < 17^{14}$$

Answer (score 3):

$31^{11} < 34^{11}$

$34^{11} = (17\times2)^{11} = (17^{11}) \times (2^{11}) = 17^{11} \times 2^4 \times 2^4 \times 2^3$

$17^{11} \times 2^4 \times 2^4 \times 2^3 < 17^{11} \times 17 \times 17 \times 17$

$17^{11} \times 17 \times 17 \times 17 = 17^{14}$

Therefore, $31^{11} < 17^{14}$

This is easy and clear. I think this will help you.

Comment: [With mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) it might have been clear.

Comment: @element118 thanks friend for valuable edit .

Answer (score 3):

Consider the :
$$1 < \left(\frac{17}{31}\right)^{11}\cdot17^{3}$$
Now the major fact:
$17^{3}>2^{11}$, i hope you could continue it!

Answer (score 2):

$17^{14}=168377826559400929$ and $31^{11}=25408476896404831$.  QED.

Comment: I'm assuming this question is not to be done with a calculator. Even if you did this in your head/ on paper there are probably faster ways to do it.

Comment: @Cataline I know, I was just being a punk.  And for the record I didn't use a calculator, I used command-line Python.

Comment: I think that counts as a calculator...

Comment: @Element118 That's like calling Sam's club a corner convenience store.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following equivalent inequalities
$$
\begin{align}
31^{11} &< 17^{14} \\
31^{10} \; 31 &< 17^{10} \; 17^4 \\
31 \; \sqrt[10]{31} &< 17 \; \sqrt[10]{17^4}
\end{align}
$$
and observe that the last one holds because
$$
\frac{31}{17} < 2 < \sqrt[10]{\frac{17^3}{2}} < \sqrt[10]{\frac{17^4}{31}}
$$
since $17^3/2 > 17^2 \; 8$ and $17^2 > 12^2 = 144 > 128 = 2^7$.